# Tax calculate in woocommerce mini cart

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, cart, tax

I want to show tax rate in woocommerce mini cart like this-> http://nimb.ws/gBGAD0 display on checkout page. That's possible? If possible please let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: yes it possible. check this document https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/setting-up-taxes-in-woocommerce/

Comment: Yes i see that but not like that. I want to show exactly same like on checkout page. See this checkout page screen shot ->  http://nimb.ws/gBGAD0 i want that Tax same like on woocommerce mini cart widget sidebar Here -> http://nimb.ws/IJUxEn. So please review this and if you know solutions then please help me.